# Trying to boot to SpinRite and get InitDiskill WARNING: using suspect partition

Tags: boot, usb, acer-aspire, spinrite

Trying to run SpinRite 6 on an `Acer Aspire z3760`, an all-in-one.

First thing I tried was booting the machine to SpinRite image on a USB; the machine simply refused to boot from the USB, even when I  went into the BIOS and made the USB the first device to boot from.

Then I burnt the SpinRite to an ISO and put that on a CD. I set the CD as the first device to boot from and got this..

```
FreeDOS kernel version 1.1.32a (Build 2032a) 
[Sep 24 2003 21:58:48] Kernel compatibility 7.10 WATCOMC FAT32 support (C) Copyright 1995-2003 Pasquale J. Uillani and The FreeDOS Project. 
All Rights Reserved. This is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY MO WARRANTY; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2, or (at your option) any later version. 
InitDiskill WARNING: using suspect partition Pri:1 FS Oc: with calculated values 38912-254-63 instead of 1021-254-63
```

Any clues what I  can do about this?

Comment: If your disk is larger then 2 TB then it is incompatible with SpinRite.  If your disk supports 4K sectors it also is not supported.

Comment: It's definitely not larger than 2TB; not sure of sector size. Will look tomorrow.

Comment: You need to disable "Secure-boot" and enable "Legacy support" before booting SpinRite. Success will also depend on the type of the disk controller.